# Display the value of \textwidth in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to display the value of \textwidth in a tikz node but below code seems doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {\textwidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I define a macro, it seems works fine.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {\the\textwidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Without a picture, because there is only value 390pt and no shape of the node.)